# Route doesn't update react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Route doesn't change when i clicking on `<Link />`

Browser hash changed but view - don't

**Routes**

```
<Router {...this.props}>
                <Route  path="/" component={App}>
                    <Route path="/profile" onEnter={this.requireAuth}>
                        <IndexRoute component={Profile} />
                        <Route path="/profile/update" component={ProfileUpdate} onEnter={this.requireAuth} />
                        <Route path="/profile/:id" component={User} ></Route>
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Router>
```

So i'm trying to navigate there `/profile/:id`

**Here is my link button**

```
<Link to={`/profile/${item.id}`}>
       Example link
</Link>
```

Also when i manually write `id` in my browser i'm getting error in my console but view shown

```
http://myapp.localhost/profile/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

How to resolve problems? 
Thanks

Comment: I think your path inside /profile are wrong try /update and /:id instead of /profile/update and /profile/:id. The 404 is normal if you are using browserHistory the server should be updated to rewrite the url to your index

Comment: Please post a component with this problem.

Comment: You should dev with hashHistory, to avoid (apache/ngninx/...) bad routing

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `item.id` is not undefined, if so Link is propably trying to change route from **/profile**  to **/profile**. Since urls are the same react-router won't do anything.